# Is attempting (committing) suicide a crime?

Tags: united-states, suicide

This post: https://law.stackexchange.com/a/7700/1272

Actually made me curious about attempting suicide is a crime in the USA?

Since in germany it isn't a crime.

Actually as far as I know, anyone knowing about it and not acting to prevent it would commit a crime.

But now I'm asking about the USA:

Is it a crime to attempt suicide?

Comment: Can you cite "Actually as far as I know, anyone knowing about it and not acting to prevent it would commit a crime."? I am fairly certain only specific professions are obligate to report any crime (therapists, teachers, police). If attempted suicide is not a crime then it is especially unlikely it is illegally not to report it.

Comment: I assume you could construct some case where not acting (by trying to stop the person, or by calling for help) when witnessing a suicide attempt is similar to not helping a car accident victim (the latter of which *would* be illegal at least in Germany http://dejure.org/gesetze/StGB/323c.html  - no idea about U.S. though).

Comment: @Sam not necessarily, see http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/3671/at-what-point-does-refusal-to-report-a-crime-make-one-an-accomplice-to-a-crime

Comment: @Dale M your link provides nothing to counteract my statement. "not necessarily" is not at all helpful.