# Is escaping prison a crime?

Tags: criminal-law, punishment, sweden, prison

Is it actually illegal to escape from a prison or will it just have effect on increased sentence in practice? I heard something that in Sweden where I live it is not illegal to escape, but is that no matter what you did?

Comment: Related: [If you escaped from prison for a crime you did not commit, would you still serve the increased sentence once exonerated?](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/7690/10)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Chapter 26 section 7 of the [Swedish Penal Code](http://www.government.se/contentassets/5315d27076c942019828d6c36521696e/swedish-penal-code.pdf) points to a possible consequence of prison escape:

> If the  sentenced  person  seriously  violates  the  conditions  for 
>   the serving  of  the  sentence  in  a  prison,  the  date  for 
>   conditional  release may be postponed. Such  a  postponement  may 
>   amount  to  at  most  fifteen  days  on each occasion of use.

Aiding an escape is a specifically-identified crime, but apparently the act of escaping is not, though is would have a negative consequence (we would say that such a treatment is an "infraction", not a separate crime).

[This article](http://scholarship.law.berkeley.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2310&context=californialawreview) in fn. 7 indicates that it is not a crime in Germany, and The Interwebs tells me the same thing. Mexican law explicitly declares that there is no penalty for prison escape ([Article 154](http://info4.juridicas.unam.mx/ijure/tcfed/8.htm?s=), with translation from [here](https://postitrandom.wordpress.com/2015/05/14/these-are-the-countries-where-prison-breaking-escape-is-legal-and-not-punishable/))

> To the prisoner that to escape (from prison) will not be given any
>   penalty, except when it’s in complicity with one or more other
>   prisoners and they perform violence on other people, in which case the
>   penalty is six months to three years in prison.

It is a specific crime in the US (governed by individual jurisdictions). The state of Washington in [RCW 9A.76.110](http://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=9A.76.110) makes general prison escape a class B felony. Adjacent provisions increase the severity of the crime if the person is a sexually violent predator (9A.76.115), reduces the crime if it is escape from detention (not pursuant to a conviction), and further reduces the crime if it is just escape from custody (e.g. escapes from the drunk tank).